# The countable intersection of measurable sets is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If this holds for 2 sets, this can be shown to hold for n sets by induction later on.

Let $E_1,E_2 \subset \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgues measurable and $E=E_1\cap E_2 \neq \emptyset$

I want to show that $$\lambda_* (A) = \lambda_* (A\cap E) + \lambda_*(A\cap E^c) \quad \forall A \subset \mathbb{R}$$

Where $\lambda_*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure

The only assumption is that I know the result for countable unions

My attempt:

$$\lambda_* (A\cap E) + \lambda_*(A\cap E^c) = \lambda_* (A\cap E_1 \cap E_2) + \lambda_*(A\cap (E_1 \cap E_2)^c)$$

And mostly from there I try and rearrange using the fact that $E_1, E_2$ are measurable but it's not working out nicely like in the proof for countable unions.

I also tried using the fact that $(E_1 \cup E_2)$ is measurable but that didn't get me anywhere and all the other answers on the site use facts that come later on that I'm not supposed to use.

I'm kind of at loss, I would appreciate any hints or solutions

Comment: Don't the measurable sets form a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: yes, but i cannot use this fact, my prof wants us to prove it using the outer measure properties and the fact that this is true for countable unions

Comment: You know the result for the union, prove the result for the complement.

Comment: right! I'll try it out, thx

Comment: @JoseCruz wow that was staring at me right in the face, thank you!